# How to round to the correct nearest number in Linux bc?

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

How do we round to the correct nearest number in a Linux basic calculator BC?

Comment: Do you want to round up or down and on what criteria? For example, should 1.3 round to 1 or 2? Should 1.7 round to 1 or 2? How about 1.5?

Comment: @NasirRiley Assuming that the OP is meaning to round is to the *nearest integer*, it stands to reason that `1.3` should go down to `1` and that `1.7` should go up to `2`. The problem is with `1.5` where both `1` and `2` are at the same distance. The usual rounding done by IEEE-754 is the bankers rounding, once up and once down on x.5 .

Answer (score 2):

One sample way is to add `0.5` and use division by 1:

```
b=1.3
(b+0.5)/1
c=1.7
(c+0.5)/1
```

Comment: How about negative numbers?

Comment: How about when `scale` is not 0?

Comment: @UncleBilly, `scale` on standard setting work fine. If you set it to nonzero you get what you make. About negative numbers AFAIK this will work fine for them

Comment: Related to using `scale` in `bc` (and to this particular question, as it happens, even though they dropped the mentioning of `scale` on this site for whatever reason): https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2021-09/msg00103.html

Comment: Thank you @they , quite interesting :)

Comment: @they, then again, in that discussion, the obvious way to write it is `bc -l <<< 'a = e(1.4*l(500)); scale = 0; (a+0.5)/1'` which gives 6006 or `bc -l <<< 'a = e(1.4*l(500)); scale = 2; (a*100+0.5)/100'` which gives `6005.62`.

Comment: Watch for negative numbers. Your solution round toward -inf, [IEEE-754 rounds to nearest (even)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3448/610623).

Comment: Seriously? This will work "fine"? In wtf definition of "rounding" `-1.9` turns into `-1` and `-1.4` into `0`?

Comment: As to "you get what you make if you set the scale to nonzero" that's so utterly lame it makes me wonder if this is real.